# Mail body displaying the HTML tags instead of actual message

Tags: php

Code is working find for gmail, yahoo, but for corporate ID, it is displaying HTML tags instead actual message..  some thing like below

```
Content-type: text/xhtml; charset=iso-8859-1

From: info@test.net

X-Mailer: php
Message-Id: <20130424005039.50FF769A98@test.=myweb.org>
Date: Wed, 24 Apr 2013 05:50:39 -0500 (CDT)
```

1. when code is commited in client pc, when we use other then corporate id, code works fine, only problem for corporate id.
2. if mail sending to corporate id from other hosting (php ), again html displays fine. i dont know what should i do now.

Snippet from php.net code.

```
$to .= 'mytomailid@mail.com';

// subject
$subject = 'Birthday Reminders for August';
// message
$message = '
<html>
<head>
  <title>Birthday Reminders for August</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Person</th><th>Day</th><th>Month</th><th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Joe</td><td>3rd</td><td>August</td><td>1970</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sally</td><td>17th</td><td>August</td><td>1973</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try library [PHP Mailer](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer) for mail sending. It handled such type of header condition.